# Encode mp3 from Finder in OS X

Tags: macos, automator, lame

I'd like to convert a WAV or AIFF to MP3 with a right click in Finder.

Not seeing any actions in automator I could use.  I don't want to add it to iTunes to do it (and also duplicate it).  I downloaded lame, but seem to have no clue how to install it - command not found when I type it while in the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sam, you have to place lame in a folder of your choice.
/Users/Sam/lame  , for instance.

Then you need to make lame executable.
Go into /Users/Sam/ on your Terminal, and type
chmod +x lame

Now you can close your terminal, and return back to your Automator script.

select "Run Shell Script".

If you intend to use your Automator script for multiple files, instead of one single file, type this:

```
for f in "$@"
do
/Users/sam/lame -b 320 -h  "$f"
done
```

This will start LAME and start encoding your MP3 at the 320kbps bitrate.

Comment: Easiest thing for me has just been to create a compressor droplet which does the same thing when I drag files onto it.  Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 0):

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4092/run-command-line-script-from-finders-contextual-menu

Replace the exif command with the lame command, based on the man page.